# Visual Basic: Sub vs. Function and Module vs. Class

Tags: vb.net

Here's a bit of an abstract question. Would it be appropriate to say that a Sub is to a Function what a Module is to a Class? The purpose of a function is to return something - a sub acts like a function but doesn't return anything. The purpose of a class is to be instantiated - a method acts like a class but can't be instantiated.

Is this a good analogy?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a real question and I don't think that this is a particularly useful or accurate analogy.

Comment: sub... modules.. is this vb.net related???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no. It's more like a module is to a class what a Shared Sub/Function is to a normal instance Sub/Function.